# How to plan for schema changes in an SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, schema

I am currently developing an application that will store data in an [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. The database will have much more read- than write-access (in fact, it will be filled with data once, and then almost only reading will happen). The read-performance is therefore much mre important. The schema I am currently developing is very likely to change in the future, with additional columns and tables being added. I do not have very much experience with databases in general. My question is, specifically in SQLite, are there any pitfalls to be considered when changing a schema? Are there any patterns or best practices to plan ahead for such cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Don't use `select * from ...`  because the meaning of `*` changes with schema changes; explicitly name the columns your query uses
2. Keep the schema version number in the database and keep code in the application to convert from schema version N to version N+1; then all the code in the application works with the latest schema version; this may mean having default values to fill added columns
3. You can avoid copying tables for schema updates with SQLite version 3.1.3 or better which supports `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN...`

Answer (score 0):

Look into data-marts and star schema design.  This might be overkill for your situation, but at least it will prevent you from designing at random.